# how many zookeeper servers we need for huge kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we build 18 kafka machines in cluster , kafka version is 1.0 , on linux machines

for now we have 3 zookeeper servers , but we not know if 3 zookeeper servers are enough for 18 Kafka machines

please advice how many zookeeper servers we need to serve 18 Kafka machines ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of Zookeepers nodes are not directly tied to the number of brokers in your cluster.

3 Zookeeper nodes should be enough, although, it's good to understand what are the trade-offs here:

> ZooKeeper uses majority quorums, which means that every voting that
> happens in one of these protocols requires a majority to vote on.

[Source - Zookeeper Quorums](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/zookeeperInternals.html#sc_quorum)

> In a production environment, the ZooKeeper servers will be deployed on
> multiple nodes. This is called an ensemble. An ensemble is a set of `2n + 1`
> ZooKeeper servers where `n` is any number greater than 0. The odd number of servers allows ZooKeeper to perform majority elections for
> leadership.

[Source - Confluent ZooKeeper Multi-node Setup](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/zookeeper/deployment.html#multi-node-setup)

So, you can use a *single node* ZK in a standalone mode, but you won't be fault-tolerant **at all**.
Using a ***3** nodes* ensemble, will allow you to lose a **single** node, and still functioning well.
Using a ***5** nodes* ensemble, will allow you to lose 2 nodes, and still functioning well.
Using a ***7** nodes* ensemble, will allow you to lose 3 nodes, and still functioning well.
etc.